# Can vue-router open a link in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a summary page and a detail subpage. All of the routes are implemented with `vue-router` (v 0.7.x) using programmatic navigation like this:

```
this.$router.go({ path: "/link/to/page" })
```

However, when I route from the summary page to the subpage, I need to open the subpage in a new tab just as one would by adding `_target="blank"` to an `<a>` tag.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I dont think thats possible with vue router, you might extract and build your url and then use window.open(url, '_blank')

Comment: Yes, they officially say it's impossible. Thank you.

Comment: there is an answer below that works, you should accept that as the response on your question, don't you think?

Comment: i go over all the answers and only thing i did was adding `target="_blank" ` to inside my router-link tag. but i am not sure if this is good practice or not. and I don't have any param

Answer (score 360, accepted):

I think that you can do something like this:

```
const routeData = this.$router.resolve({name: 'routeName', query: {data: "someData"}});
window.open(routeData.href, '_blank');
```

It worked for me.

**Update**

---

For composition Api:

```
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
const router = useRouter();
const routeData = router.resolve({name: 'routeName', query: {data: "someData"}});
window.open(routeData.href, '_blank');
```

Comment: This seems like the best way to me. You still use $router to build the url without having to mash together some hacky string, then use window to open the new tab. +1

Comment: Unfortunately this method get block by some default browser popup blocker

Comment: Note that location parameter uses `path` instead of `name` if you use `query`.

Comment: One problem with this is that window.open does not pass headers like tokens and others.

Comment: @Rafel,  May i ask you to have a look at a Vue.JS question related with the source code in github of the book 'Full-Stack Vue.js 2 and Laravel 5' by Anthone Gore here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245577/laravel-vuejs-router-view-does-not-render-the-component ? Particularly take a look at the EDIT: section of the OP ?

Comment: Create a link instead, like `<a :href="getPath" target="_blank">...</a>` ; avoid using Javascript to open links for accessibility, SEO & security reasons. What's more a link will still work even if there're errors in your JS code that break your app.

Comment: In addition... if you don't want to open a new tab that is already open. It's possible to configure the `target` with an id of the refereced value with some other identification. Like `window.open(routeData.href, 'details ' + id);`

Answer (score 224):

It seems like this is now possible in newer versions (Vue Router 3.0.1):

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'fooRoute'}" target="_blank">
  Link Text
</router-link>
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to be that you can pass parameters though? just open the link itself. Correct?

Comment: @Gotts you can pass params and queryparams also. The code shall for doing that is given below
<router-link :to="{ name: 'fooRoute',params:{param_var:'id_parameter'},query:{query_var:'query_params'}}" target="_blank">
  Link Text
</router-link>

Comment: Note that this is for the <router-link>, it doesn't work programmatically with `this.$router.push()`.

Comment: adding target property in the router-link.  This is awesome.  The answer above by @Harish seem to work as well if we need the logic in the routes declarations.

Comment: <router-link :to="{ name: 'fooRoute', params: { id: 132 } }">
                Link Text
              </router-link>

Answer (score 25):

For those who are wondering the answer is no.
See related [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/768#issuecomment-253505307) on github.

> Q: Can vue-router open link in new tab progammaticaly
>
> A: No. use a normal link.

Comment: Now possible to add `target="_blank"` to a `<router-link>` tag in v3 https://stackoverflow.com/a/49654382/2678454

Comment: Found this very helpful instead of constructing the full URL and using window.open

Comment: A: Yes for Vue 3+, now its possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49654382/9950567

Answer (score 21):

In case that you define your route like the one asked in the question (path: '/link/to/page'):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue';

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/link/to/page',
      component: MyComponent
    }
  ]
})
```

You can resolve the URL in your summary page and open your sub page as below:

```
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    popup() {
      let route = this.$router.resolve({path: '/link/to/page'});
      // let route = this.$router.resolve('/link/to/page'); // This also works.
      window.open(route.href, '_blank');
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Of course if you've given your route a name, you can resolve the URL by name:

```
routes: [
  {
    path: '/link/to/page',
    component: MyComponent,
    name: 'subPage'
  }
]

...

let route = this.$router.resolve({name: 'subPage'});
```

References:

- vue-router [router.resolve(location, current?, append?)](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-instance.html#methods)
- vue-router [router-link](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html)

Answer (score 13):

Somewhere in your project, typically main.js or router.js

```
import Router from 'vue-router'

Router.prototype.open = function (routeObject) {
  const {href} = this.resolve(routeObject)
  window.open(href, '_blank')
}
```

In your component:

```
<div @click="$router.open({name: 'User', params: {ID: 123}})">Open in new tab</div>
```

Comment: Not down-voting, but maybe it's nice for Vue3?  Because console/logging this.$router.open returns undefined for me

Comment: This approach is discouraged as it mutates prototype. You can't log it, because it isn't part of the spec.

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me-

```
let routeData = this.$router.resolve(
{
  path: '/resources/c-m-communities', 
  query: {'dataParameter': 'parameterValue'}
});
window.open(routeData.href, '_blank');
```

I modified @Rafael_Andrs_Cspedes_Basterio answer

Answer (score 11):

Just write this code in your routing file :

```
{
  name: 'Google',
  path: '/google',
  beforeEnter() {                    
                window.open("http://www.google.com", 
                '_blank');
            }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I think the best way is to simply use:

```
window.open("yourURL", '_blank');
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested ONLY on relative paths like: `/dashboard`, `/about` etc, See other answers.

If you want to open an absolute path like: `https://www.google.com` to a new tab, you have to know that Vue Router is NOT meant to handle those.

However, they seems to consider that as a feature-request. [#1280](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1280). But until they do that,

---

---

> Here is a little trick you can do to handle external links with vue-router.

- Go to the router configuration (probably `router.js`) and add this code:

```js
/* Vue Router is not meant to handle absolute urls. */
/* So whenever we want to deal with those, we can use this.$router.absUrl(url) */
Router.prototype.absUrl = function(url, newTab = true) {
  const link = document.createElement('a')
  link.href = url
  link.target = newTab ? '_blank' : ''
  if (newTab) link.rel = 'noopener noreferrer' // IMPORTANT to add this
  link.click()
}
```

> Now, whenever we deal with absolute URLs we have a solution. For example to open google to a new tab

```
this.$router.absUrl('https://www.google.com)
```

**Remember that whenever we open another page to a new tab we MUST use `noopener noreferrer`.**

[Read more here](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/)

[or Here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/noopener)

Comment: works well for me on almost all devices except mobile phones, where the new window does not open!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way of doing this using an anchor tag would be this:

```
<a :href="$router.resolve({name: 'posts.show', params: {post: post.id}}).href" target="_blank">
    Open Post in new tab
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Below code is to open a new tab with parameter.**

With router link=

```
<router-link
                  :to="{ name: 'task_section',query: {reportId: item.task,}}"
                  target="_blank"> Link Text
              </router-link>
```

Now access to the sented data

```
this.$route.query.reportId
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by creating a separate method for window redirect like this.

```js
const openLinkInNewTab = (url) => {
  window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

then use it on `template` like this

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="openLinkInNewTab('https://devsbuddy.com')">
    Open in new tab
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

In HTML template:
`<a target="_blank" :href="url" @click.stop>your_name</a>`

In mounted():
`` this.url = `${window.location.origin}/your_page_name`; ``

Answer (score 0):

you can use it in vue3 & typescript

```
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
const router = useRouter();
let route = router.resolve({ name:'/link/to/page' , query: { param: 'param1' } });
window.open(route.fullPath, "_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code for apache server

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).