# set target= '_blank' in router-link of vuejs 2.5

Tags: vuejs2, routerlink

Using vuejs 2.5 if there is a way in router-link to set

```
target= '_blank'
```

?
I tried this way:

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'UserProfileView', params: {id: participantUser.user_id}, target: '_blank' }"  >
```

but failed...

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can vue-router open a link in new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015037/can-vue-router-open-a-link-in-new-tab)

Answer (score 33):

You will add `target='_blank'` like on `<a>` tag

Hope is clear

Comment: so it will be something like:

`<router-link :to="{name: 'UserProfileView', params: {id: participantUser.user_id}}"   target= '_blank' >`

Comment: it won't work if tag is not a (for example tag="button")

Comment: @igor i think because by default router-link is an anchor tag with the target property, the button html element don't have it

Comment: @kalidou.diagne you mean in the router-link tag ?

Comment: @SalmaELHAJRAOUI, like the example on the first comment 

`<router-link   target= '_blank' >my link </router-link>`

Answer (score 1):

You must to use method. Method looks something like this:

```
methods: {
     redirectToUserView(user) {
      const route = this.$router.resolve({
        name: 'UserProfileView',
        params: {id: participantUser.user_id},   
      });
      window.open(route.href, '_blank');
    },
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below code is to open a new tab with parameter.**

With router link=

```
<router-link
                  :to="{ name: 'task_section',query: {reportId: item.task,}}"
                  target="_blank"> Link Text
              </router-link>
```

Now access to the sented data

```
this.$route.query.reportId
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly worked for my code "`target='_blank'`" with external redirect.

```
<b-dropdown-item
                :key="props.row.banner_id"
                :to="{name:'banners-preview',
                      params: { id: props.row.banner_id } }"
                target='_blank'
              >
                <feather-icon
                  icon="ExternalLinkIcon"
                  class="mr-50"
                />
                <span>Preview Link</span>
</b-dropdown-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <button @click="gotoContact()">Contact</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "app",
  methods: {
    gotoContact() {
      let route = this.$router.resolve({ path: "/contact" });
      window.open(route.href);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```