# Nuxt: How to open page in a new tab

Tags: vue-router, nuxt.js

I go through the documentation of Nuxt, but couldn't find information about how to open a page in a new tab. Is there a way to open a link in a new tab instead of opening it in the current tab? I tried the following code:

```
<nuxt-link to="/user" target="_blank">User</nuxt-link>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Adding attribute `target="_blank"` [now works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49654382/2278963)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The whole point of vue-router is navigating inside a single page application so it doesn't have a way to navigate to a blank new tab as far as I know. Fortunately there is an old fashioned thing called 'html' which has something called an anchor tag that you can use like this:

```
<a href="/user" target="_blank">User</a>
```

Comment: Love your cynicism

Comment: Nuxt 3 Nuxt-link adds the rel=”noreferrer noopener” to external links, so it is advised to use NuxtLink for external links as well, if you're using Nuxt 3

Answer (score 17):

As @anthonygore pointed out in a comment to first post.
It's now working to open link in a new tab by , having all the features of router name/path link

do it with by adding `target="_blank"` to/inside NuxtLink to have

```js
<NuxtLink :to="..." target="_blank">Nuxt link to external page</NuxtLink>
```

or just use default

```js
<a href="..." target="_blank">A link to external page</a>
```

Comment: I think the closing tag in the upper example should be `</NuxtLink> ` instead of `</a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="./user" target="_blank">User</a>
```

Note that the path should start with dot. If the website is not at root.