# Error with opening url in other tab in js code

Tags: vuejs2, routes

In my Laravel 5.8 / "vue": "^2.6.10"/ app 
I need to open url in other tab in js code. I found example

```
let routeData = this.$router.resolve({name: 'routeName', query: {data: "someData"}});
window.open(routeData.href, '_blank');
```

here
[Can vue-router open a link in a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015037/can-vue-router-open-a-link-in-a-new-tab)

but implementing it I did not find valid way :

```
let routeData = this.$router.resolve(  {name: 'editHostel', query: {params: { id : 48 } }  });


            OR

let routeData = this.$router.resolve(  {name: 'editHostel', query: {id: date.id}}  );


        window.open(routeData.href, '_blank');
```

in both case generated url was invalid.

In resources/js/routes.js I have :

```
{
    path: '/admin/hostels',
    component: hostelsContainer,
    meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        authGroupsAccess: ['Admin', 'Manager'],
    },
    children: [
        {
            path: '/admin/hostels/',
            component: hostelsList,
            name: 'listHostels'
        },
        {
            path: '/admin/hostels/new',
            component: editHostel,
            name: 'newHostel'
        },
        {
            path: ':id',
            component: editHostel,
            name: 'editHostel'
        },
```

Which way is valid ?

Comment: Are you making Single Page Application within laravel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a decision based on link  [Can vue-router open a link in a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015037/can-vue-router-open-a-link-in-a-new-tab)
as :

```
let routeData = this.$router.resolve(  { path: '/admin/hostels/' + date.originalEvent.hostel_id +"/open_hostel_inquery_feedback/"+date.id});
window.open(routeData.href, '_blank');
```

That works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Don't make **SPA**(single page application) within laravel. 
If you really want to create  **SPA** then use **vue cli**

Otherwise, use vue.js as a replacement for jQuery. That gives you more power of making an interactive website using laravel and vue.js in a single project.

You will be able to use blade views where you don't have to use vue and vice versa.

Comment: Afraz Ahmad, though your answer seems off topic, I am intereted :1) please, a bit more detailed why? 2) what can be used for db operations?
3) Please, provide a link with examples of proper SPA with db operations implementation...

Comment: what do you mean by db operations ? Are you talking about ajax calls to server ? If yes then you can use axios  https://github.com/axios/axios  to do so.

Comment: Look at this https://github.com/gothinkster/vue-realworld-example-app this is very good repo. But they are using best practices that can be overwhelming at first.

Comment: Thanks for the link, very interesting, but where is part working with db?
I mean read/write data from/to db. Some it be some different app, as api endpoint ?
 
In the source of t5he app I found link to 
https://conduit.productionready.io/api
Is it some api endpoint ?

Comment: It is SPA in vue.js + vuex. It is using APIs to handle DB part.

Comment: If there DB part public ?