# How to open a vue component in new tab without page load by vue router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Is it possible to open a Vue component in new tab by vue router without page reload.

#### Normal Way :

```html
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">HtmlExample </a>
```

#### Vue Router

```html
<router-link to="/example" target="_blank">Vue Router Example </a>
```

It's works properly but i need it without page reload.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can vue-router open a link in a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015037/can-vue-router-open-a-link-in-a-new-tab)

Comment: "without page reload" What do you mean here? Like the current page or the page you are opening in a new tab. A new tab is a completely separate browser process so the answer would be no.

Comment: Everything is work properly no problem but I want to any if there any process available to switch one component to another component by Vue router in another tab.  @JaredMcAteer

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do this with a simple router link. If you want to control another window you'll probably need to use the [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) API and implement some system for communicating between the windows. You might be able to spawn a popup window with a specific id and set the target to the window id instead of "blank" but I don't think if pushState will work that way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your issue correctly: new pages are always going to be loaded, since it's a vue lifecycle. [Vue lifecycles](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html). But what you can do here is to use browser's local storage. And when the component is mounted for example, you can share the data from your previous page.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30577012)