# I want to open this router link in a new tab instead of same tab

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

This is my function which directs to the page route

**.ts file**

```
readmoreFunc(data:any){
this.showId = data._id;
this.contentType =data.type
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/dashboard-content/', this.showId,this.contentType])}
```

showId and contentType are my params. for eg"(http://localhost:4200/dashboard/dashboard-content/ckhewcmcj000v98t9zcb89rz0/Recent-Post) i want to open it in another tab in chrome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can vue-router open a link in a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015037/can-vue-router-open-a-link-in-a-new-tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 const url = this.router.serializeUrl(
        this.router.createUrlTree([`/dashboard/dashboard-content/${this.showId}/${this.contentType}`])
      );
 window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you. It opens in a new tab and works fine.