# Make v-data-table rows opens in new tab (vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm currently using vuetify and I need to make each row act as `a` tag and make sure it's opens in new tab.

My table looks like this:

```
<v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="campaigns"
        calculate-widths
        :loading="loading"
        :search="search"
        :items-per-page="15"
        @click:row="showCampaignReport"
      >
</v-data-table>
```

I'm using `@click:row="showCampaignReport"` now and it works fine but the problem is that there is no open link in new tab in browser context menu...

```js
showCampaignReport(value) {
    this.$router.push({ path: `/campaigns/${value.hash}` });
},
```

Comment: Can you share `showCampaignReport` function?

Comment: If you need the `open link in new tab` to appear in the context menu - you must wrap the content of each table cell inside A tags.

Comment: @IVOGELOV yeah I know that I should wrap it inside a tag. but I don't know how can I do it in an efficient way

Comment: @scar-2018 I edited my question and added the details of `showCampaignReport`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late reply.
The question was already posted and you can find in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015037/can-vue-router-open-a-link-in-a-new-tab)